# ContentDialog in ModernWPF

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a `ContentDialog` using `ModernWpf.Controls` but it does not work properly and it appears  [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlhRU.png)

Here is the code :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = "its pretty Small",
                Content = "Yea...",
            }.ShowAsync();
        }
```

Comment: And what is your specific question? What is "not working properly"? Please show us what you tried, and describe the issue. Also, please read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about the missing buttons, you will need to set a few more properties:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = "its pretty Small",
            Content = "Yea...",
            PrimaryButtonText = "Yes",
            SecondaryButtonText = "No"
        }.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for your answer. You might improve your answer by explaining *why/how* this solves the posted question.